# Format string not working in C# getter

Tags: c#, string, datetime-format

I need to format data string from format "dd.mm.yyyy" to be "yyyymmdd". I'm trying to do this following way, but this return unchanged string.

```
 private string _pe1;
 public string PassportEnd1 { 
    get { return String.Format("{0:yyyymmdd}", this._pe1); }
    set { this._pe1 = value; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really strange way for conversion. Function would fit better for this.
But if you insist on using property then use it like this:

```
private DateTime _pe1;
public string PassportEnd1
{
    get { return _pe1.ToString("yyyymmdd"); }
    set { _pe1 = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd.mm.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
}
```